# How to extract string between same char

Tags: c#

I have a string "ABD-DDD-RED-Large" and need to extract "DDD-RED"

using the Split I have:

```
  var split = "ABD-DDD-RED-Large".Split('-');
  var first = split[0];
  var second = split[1];
  var third = split[2];
  var fourth = split[3];
  string value = string.Join("-", second, third);
```

just wondering if there's a shorter code

Comment: If your code works and you're looking for critique or improvements, ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: `string value = string.Join("-", "ABD-DDD-RED-Large".Split('-').Skip(1).Take(2));`

Comment: @maccettura why not just use Substring `string result = "ABD-DDD-RED-Large".Substring(4, 7);`

Comment: @SlavenTojić I imagined the OP had a string that was in 4 parts (separated by `-`).  If not, then this entire question is pointless as they could just have hard coded it

Comment: @maccettura you've got a point there, my solution makes only sense if the input string is always in the format `XXX-XXX-XXX-Large`

Comment: strings are not static....thanks!

Comment: What are the actual requirements here?  Slaven Tojić provided a great answer, shorter code for this specific example.  Is your input string always 4 substrings divided by a hyphen?  Are all of those substrings always the same length (ie first part 3 chars, second part 3 chars, etc etc)?  Do you specifically need the parts between the FIRST and LAST hyphen, and this will ALWAYS be the case, regardless of length of any of the substrings?

Comment: What are expected results for string like "ABD-DDD" or "A-B-C-D-E-F" ?

Comment: @maccettura your solution is missing in the answers

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the second and third parts of an always 4 part (delimited by `-`) string you can one line it with LINQ:

```
string value = string.Join("-", someInputString.Split('-').Skip(1).Take(2));
```

An input of: `"ABD-DDD-RED-Large"` would give you an output of: `"DDD-RED"`

Comment: I like this.  The logic is doing exactly what OP's original code does, but in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb and assuming your string is always FOUR substrings divided by THREE hyphens.  The main benefit of doing it this way is that it only requires the basic String library.

You can use:

```
int firstDelIndex = input.IndexOf('-');
int lastDelIndex = input.LastIndexOf('-');
int neededLength = lastDelIndex - firstDelIndex - 1;
result = input.Substring((firstDelIndex + 1), neededLength);
```

This is generic enough to not care what any of the actual inputs are except the hyphen character.

You may want to add a catch at the start of the method using this to ensure there are at least two hyphen's in the input string before trying to pull out the requested substring.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information. You mentioned that string is not static. May be Regex?

```
string input = "ABD-DDD-RED-Large";
string pattern = @"(?i)^[a-z]+-([a-z]+-[a-z]+)";
string s = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use regex

```
var match = Regex.Match(split, @".*?-(.*?-.*?)-.*?");
var value = match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : string.Empty;
```